# How to lock if condition until both conditions are true?

Tags: java

I have a program which parses last one hour data from a log file and keeps it in another file. I need to keep the condition running until the program finds one hour data. The one hour data will be written inside the log file by a server.

How do I keep the condition running until it finds one hour data?

```
ReversedLinesFileReader reverse= new ReversedLinesFileReader(file);
PrintWriter writer= new PrintWriter(f2+"/"+fileName1); ;
String line;
while ((line = reverse.readLine()) != null) {
    List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(line);
    if(line.contains(Constants.SPEEDO)) {
        timeFromLine = getTimeFromLine(line);
        timeFromSystem= getSystemTime();

        timeGap= propertiesReader.getPropertyValue("timeGap");
        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        timeLine= format.parse(timeFromLine);
        timeSystem=format.parse(timeFromSystem);
        timeGapDate=format.parse(timeGap);
        startTimeLong=timeSystem.getTime();
        timeGapLong=timeGapDate.getTime();
        endTimeLong=startTimeLong-timeGapLong;
        Date d= new Date(endTimeLong);
        endTimeString= format.format(d);
        endTimeDate1=format.parse(endTimeString);
        if(timeLine.before(timeSystem)&&timeLine.after(endTimeDate1)) {
            writer.println(line);
        }       
    }
}
writer.close();

reverse.close();
```

Comment: honestly, I am confused. With a very quick look, the code you have seems..ok? What do you mean by lock? What is the current behaviour that you do not want..?

Comment: Do you mean pooling the log file?

Comment: The code currently grabs one hour log file. But i want the code to wait, until the one hour data is available and then grab it and save it to a file. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Thomas Sorry, but I didnt get you? What exactly pooling is?

Comment: This http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html might be interesting for you.

Comment: @Thomas I have used file monitor [link](http://andreinc.net/2012/06/30/writing-a-simple-file-monitor-in-java-using-commons-io/) Are you talking about polling interval which is used here?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm sorry. I mean polling. :)

Comment: I have implemented polling as this

` final long pollingInterval = 3600000;`

will this make the program run every one hour? @Thomas

Comment: You could answer your own question so others can benefit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Thomas, I used polling interval to run the code in an interval.
You can find the full sample program in this [link](http://andreinc.net/2012/06/30/writing-a-simple-file-monitor-in-java-using-commons-io/)

`final long pollingInterval = 5000`